# cmake on android find_library fail to find with custom path

Tags: android, cmake, find

I failed to find_library with cmake/android, so I wrote this simple test.

```
find_library(log-lib log
  PATHS /Users/sam/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-21/arch-arm/usr/lib
  NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
```

It's Ok. Then I copy that lib directory to another location.

```
find_library(log-lib log
  PATHS /Users/sam/tmp/lib
  NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
```

Fail! I am pretty sure that I have copied the whole lib directory.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since you are cross-compiling, you must tell `CMake` that it is allowed to use a library elsewhere than specified by the toolchain (in your case, elsewhere than the Android SDK directory).

To do so, you can add this:

```
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY BOTH)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE BOTH)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE BOTH)
```

(in your case, only the first one is relevant)

More information [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html).

Comment: Fixed. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you so much - it took far too long to find this solution. I wish this was documented better!

Comment: This is the way, but i am confused, that the `BOTH` refer to [`CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY.html) says it will find `CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH` and  `CMAKE_SYSROOT`, but why it will effect the `PATHS` we set in find_library ?